# Python, using other classes __str__ methods in a different class

Tags: python, oop

This is how my `Characters` class is being used.

Python console:

```
>>> chars = Characters()
>>> chars.add(Character("Link", "Zelda"))
>>> chars.add(Enemy("Goomba", "SMB"))
>>> chars.add(Enemy("Koopa", "SMB"))
>>> chars.games()
['Zelda' 'SMB']

>>> chars.characters("SMB")
['Koopa', 'Goomba']
```

How can I make str(chars) return the following:

```
"Zelda:

Link from Zelda

SMB:

The Fearsome Koopa from SMB

The Fearsome Goomba from SMB"
```

My Attempt 
Code:

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name, game):
        self.name = name
        self.game = game
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} from {1}".format(self.name, self.game)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Character('{0}','{1}')".format(self.name, self.game)

class Enemy(Character):
    def __str__(self):
        return "The Fearsome {0} from {1}".format(self.name, self.game)

class Characters():
    def __init__(self):
        self.g = []
        self.c = {}
        self.p = {}
    def games(self):
        return (self.g)

    def characters(self, char_name):
        if char_name not in self.c:
            return []
        return self.c[char_name]

    def __str__(self):

        s = ""
        if not self.p:
            return s
        for x in self.p:
            s+=x+":"
            for y in self.p[x]:
                s+=" "+y+" "
        return s

    def add(self, obj):
       if not obj.game in self.g:
           self.g.append(obj.game)
       if not obj.game in self.c:
           self.c[obj.game] = [obj.name]
           self.p[obj.game] = [str(obj)]
       else:
           self.c[obj.game] += [obj.name]
           self.p[obj.game] += [str(obj)]
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: You can't use `> ` when posting output from the console because this is reserved for making quotes.  I edited your post to show how to do that.  See [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: I am not sure how to do the ___str___ method for the Characters class, and thank you for the editing help Bill

Comment: Not sure why others are marking down your question.  Maybe because you haven't shown any attempt to produce the desired output? Have a go at writing some code in the `__str__` method of `Characters`.

Comment: this is what I tried but it is not like the desired output with the newlines, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a new line in a string use `"\n"`.

So, this should work:

```
def __str__(self):

    s = ""
    for x in self.p:
        s += x + ":\n\n"
        for y in self.p[x]:
            s += y + "\n\n"
    return s
```

[Note: you don't need the line `if not self.p:` because the for loop will not execute if `self.p` is empty].

There are other ways you could do this.

One way is to use `join()` and `dict.items()` in a list comprehensions.

Try this:

```
def __str__(self):

    items = [
        (p + ':\n\n' + '\n\n'.join(v)) 
        for p, v in self.p.items()
    ]

    return "\n\n".join(items)
```

Note: In Python version 2, use `dict.iteritems()` instead.

Comment: When I do `str(chars)` my output comes out as                                               `'Zelda:\n\nLink from Zelda\n\nSNM:\n\nThe Fearsome Goompa from SNM\n\n'`

Comment: That is normal.  To see the newlines printed use `print(chars)`